# Link to download the ISO 27002 clauses

Tags: iso27000

Which link is authentic to download ISO 27002 clauses. I am not seeing a web page / PDF for the list of 133 controls to go through

Comment: You can buy a PDF copy of the full specification from http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=54533 - it's not freely available.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy the standard in PDF at http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=54533 for CHF 178
or
Check the below link for entire toolkit containing all you need. For just list of Controls look for [SoA](http://www.iso27001security.com/ISO27k_SOA_2013_in_3_languages.xlsx) document.  http://www.iso27001security.com/html/iso27k_toolkit.html

Also please note that now there are 114 controls in 14 groups; the old standard had 133 controls in 11 groups. Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_27001:2013